# How can I call a paint method that has a Graphics component parameter in a class that isn't graphic(component, frame, etc)?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Sorry for my english, i'm brazilian and i don't know english very well.

So, I'm trying to do an application in java similar to CAD. The user enter with de dimensions of rectangle(this simbolizes a home and rooms) and when a buttom is clicked the component have to appear in the window.
My problem is: i have a class called JanelaPrincipal(it extends JFrame) that is the interface with the user, it has the JTextField, JButtom, etc. And i have a class within the class JanelaPrincipal, that is called AddCasa that implements mouseClicked. The class JanelaPrincipal has a paint override method, this method call a method in the Casa class. I need to call the JanelaPrincipal's paint method in the class AddCasa. It is actived when the user click in the buttom.
[JanelaPrincipal Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TXsu.jpg)

[Casa class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9Zg5.jpg)

Here is the code:
JanelaPrincipal class and AdicionarCasa class:

```
package View;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import Model.Casa;

public class JanelaPrincipal extends JFrame
{
    JLabel lCasa, lComod, lPorta, lJanela, lVao, lPassagem, lLargCasa, lProfundCasa, lIDComodo, lNomeComodo, lPosComodo, lXComodo, lYComodo, lLargComodo, lProfundComodo;
    JLabel lIDVao, lPosVao, lXVao, lYVao, lOrientacao, lTamVao, lRotPorta, lAbertPorta;
    JPanel areaDesenho;
    JTextField largCasa, profundCasa;
    JButton addCasa;
    Casa casa;
    JanelaPrincipal janelaPrincipal;
    public JanelaPrincipal()
    {
        //janelaPrincipal = new JanelaPrincipal();
        //janelaPrincipal = this;
        casa = new Casa(0,0);
        this.setSize(900, 650);//define tamanho(largura/altura)
        this.setTitle("CAD");//define um titulo para janela
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);//tem que colocar sempre

        lCasa = new JLabel("CASA");
        lCasa.setBounds(145,20,70,20);
        this.add(lCasa);

        lLargCasa = new JLabel("Largura");
        lLargCasa.setBounds(20,60,120,20);
        this.add(lLargCasa);

        largCasa = new JTextField();
        largCasa.setBounds(70,60,70,20);
        this.add(largCasa);

        lProfundCasa = new JLabel("Profundidade");
        lProfundCasa.setBounds(160, 60, 120, 20);
        this.add(lProfundCasa);

        profundCasa = new JTextField();
        profundCasa.setBounds(245, 60,80, 20);
        this.add(profundCasa);

        addCasa = new JButton("Adicionar");
        addCasa.setBounds(110, 100,110, 25);
        addCasa.addMouseListener(new AdicionarCasa());
        this.add(addCasa);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);//
        casa.desenhar(g);
    }

    public class AdicionarCasa extends MouseAdapter
    {
        int largura, profundidade;
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {
            largura = Integer.parseInt(largCasa.getText());
            profundidade = Integer.parseInt(profundCasa.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Casa class:

```
package Model;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Casa extends JPanel
{
    private int largura;
    private int profundidade;
    int numComodos;
    int numVaos;
    Comodo comodos[];
    Vao vaos[];

    public Casa(int largura, int profundidade)
    {
        this.setLargura(largura);
        this.setProfundidade(profundidade);
        comodos = new Comodo[20];
        vaos = new Vao[20];
        numComodos = 0;
        numVaos = 0;
    }
    void addComodo(Comodo c)//colocar o obj comodo no vet
    {
        comodos[numComodos] = c;
        numComodos++;
    }
    public void desenhar(Graphics g)
    {
        Comodo c;
        g.drawRect(0, 0, this.getLargura(), this.getProfundidade());
        for(int i=0;i<numComodos;i++)
        {
            c = comodos[i];
            g.drawRect(100+c.getPosX(), 10+c.getPosY(), c.getLargura(), c.getProfundidade());//desenha comodo
        }
    }
    public int getLargura() {
        return largura;
    }
    public void setLargura(int largura) {
        this.largura = largura;
    }
    public int getProfundidade() {
        return profundidade;
    }
    public void setProfundidade(int profundidade) {
        this.profundidade = profundidade;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here, not pictures of it.

Comment: _i'm brazilian and i don't know english very well_ you might want to check out https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: what? i didn't understand

Comment: You want to do some research into the concept of "model-view-controller", where your view paints the state of the model (the data). When you can a modification of the data, it generates notifications that other parties (like the view) register to and take action when generated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force a repaint of the top-level frame, you should call **revalidate()** on that component, especially if you're adding or removing a component from the frame.

In your code, the *AdicionarCasa* listener does not have a reference to the JFrame, so you'd either need to pass in a reference in the constructor, or simply implement the MouseListener interface on the JFrame itself.

Keep in mind that if you want to do a regular **paint()** operation, you'll need to ensure it is done on the Swing event thread.  The **repaint()** and **revalidate()** are thread-safe, so you don't need to run them explicitly on the Swing EDT.

Your code could either change like this:

```
addCasa.addMouseListener(new AdicionarCasa(this));
...
public class AdicionarCasa extends MouseAdapter
{
    int largura, profundidade;
    JFrame frame;
    public AdicionarCasa( JFrame parent )
    {
        frame = parent;
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        largura = Integer.parseInt(largCasa.getText());
        profundidade = Integer.parseInt(profundCasa.getText());
        // add/remove/modify components as needed
        frame.revalidate();
    }
}
```

or add the MouseListener to the frame itself:

```
public class JanelaPrincipal extends JFrame implements MouseListener
{
    ...

    void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
          // Logic from the old adapter class goes here
    }
    void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
    void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked, but i got the error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at View.JanelaPrincipal.paint(JanelaPrincipal.java:123)
 at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source). Do you have any idea what it means?
And the application spend a lot of time to "print" the rect in the window(about half an hour). Is it normal?

Comment: Without seeing the entire piece of code, there's no way to tell what the issue is.  Taking half an hour to draw on the screen is rather odd - are you sure your code didn't get stuck in some kind of loop?